# Why is the parallel gateway in BPMN 2.0 represented with perpendicular lines?

Tags: bpmn

This is not an important question but it's really bothering me more than it should.

Is there any reason why the **parallel** gateway is represented by a **perpendicular** sign?

[image: parallel gateway]

Or is this the addition symbol? Signifying that all events occur together... thus plus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh, it is a plus sign. As stated in the specifications 
http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/2.0/

It just seemed more intuitive to me to represent it with parallel lines when naming it parallel gateway.